# Boostrap fixed height cols at all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a HTML element with an image and some text next to each other positioned with bootstrap like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="avatar">
      <img src="<?= get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/dist/images/weare.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <blockquote>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Text.</p>
    </blockquote>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is when I go on a small screen the image is not taking the full size of the canvas.

[image]

and on a large screen the box for the text is way too large

[image]

I don't have much experience with bootstrap and flexbox too fix this but my goal is to have a fixed height on all screen sizes.

Comment: put your css code or use working snippet

Comment: hey @core114 I am not sure what css code is relevant for this problem I am not a designer or front end developer but I will try my best to copy the relevant css and edit OP

Comment: @SebastianBrosch it's bootstrap v4

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <div class="container-overflow-wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hidden-xs">
            <div class="row row-padded row-bordered row-centered">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="avatar">
                        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <blockquote>
                        <h1>hi this a demo</h1>
                        <p>The Moon is a barren, rocky world without air and water. It has dark lava plain on its surface. The Moon has filled with craters. It has no light of its own. It gets its light from the Sun. The Moo keeps changing its shape as it moves around the Earth. It spins on its axis in 27.3 days stars were named after the Edwin Aldrin were the first ones to set their foot on the Moon on 21 July 1969 They reached the Moon in their spacecraft named Apollo II</p>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

try this it may help you

Comment: This does nothing unfortunately, everything stays and behaves the same

Comment: Now try it it will help you

Comment: on large screens this gives the same issue, a large picture and small text I need everything fixed at 400px heigh max for example

Comment: So in large screen, you want full screen of image or half image and half text

Comment: full screen I want half image and half text but not a very large image and small text the height of everything needs to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Try like This

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="row p-2">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="avatar"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iQEpfb/Kuli_Postcard_STPATTYS2016_750x500_vz.png" alt="Kuli_Postcard_STPATTYS2016_750x500_vz" border="0" class="img-responsive"> </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <blockquote>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph.Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph.Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph.Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the u</p>
  </blockquote>
</div>



<div class="row p-2">
  <div class="col-md-6 ">
    <div class="avatar"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/iQEpfb/Kuli_Postcard_STPATTYS2016_750x500_vz.png" alt="Kuli_Postcard_STPATTYS2016_750x500_vz" border="0" class="img-responsive"> </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <blockquote>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph.Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragraph.Paragraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the unity and coherence of ideas among sentences is what constitutes a paragrParagraphs are the building blocks of papers. Many students define paragraphs in terms of length: a paragraph is a group of at least five sentences, a paragraph is half a page long, etc. In reality, though, the uaph.</p>
  </blockquote>
</div>
```